# Need to use "this" to fix to select specific area of my code

Tags: jquery, html, this

I have a similar code within different areas of my page which need to be selected and hidden/shown based on the link clicked. All I need to fix my JQuery code to somehow customize it to do things the way I want.

As an example, under a specific place on my page, there is a code:-

```
 <div class="continue" style="display: block;">
    <p>
        <span id="slider-next">
        <a class="bx-next disabled" href="">Next Question</a></span>
    </p>
 </div>
```

At another point, there is a piece of code as:-

```
<div class="continue" style="display: block;">
   <p><span id="slider-next2">
   <a class="bx-next" href="">Next Question</a></span></p>
</div>
```

I am hoping that I can control both of these chunk of codes through same JQuery snippet. Only thing I wanna achieve is that if a.bx-next has a class of `diasbled` in it, it should hide otherwise it should show. How can I do this for both by adding `this`, so JQuery should know that it should only use this code for the current area of the page and not all of the page.

Here is my JQuery

```
if ($('#slider-next a.bx-next').is(".disabled")) {
    $('#questions .continue').hide();
}
else { $('#questions .continue').show(); }
```

Thanks.

UPDATE:-

### My Complete HTML Looks like this:-

```
<li class="question">
        <div class="overview">
        <h2>Title goes here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nec hendrerit ligula. Ut non justo in massa bibendum rutrum ac eu massa. Pellentesque in arcu dui. Nulla sollicitudin dui sed commodo congue. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus ante neque, scelerisque et adipiscing sit amet, hendrerit tempus magna. Ut vel eros in sapien condimentum sodales at gravida velit. Nullam dolor enim, lobortis nec hendrerit eget, vulputate sit amet eros. Quisque varius, ligula sed luctus pretium, justo sem interdum nunc, suscipit accumsan velit nunc eget nibh. Nunc justo leo, dignissim ac est ut, lacinia dictum nulla. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla.</p> 
        </div>

        <img src="images/a-laptop-1.png" class="laptop">

        <div class="q">

            <ul class="bxslider question-slide">

                <li>

                    <p>1. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.1%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.7%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.4%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.1%</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>

                    <p>2. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.x%</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <div class="continue">
              <p>
                 <span id="slider-next"><a class="bx-next disabled" href="">Next Question</a></span></span></p>
            </div>
    </div>


</li>

<li class="question">
        <div class="overview">
        <h2>Title goes here</h2>
            <p>Quisque nec hendrerit ligula. Ut non justo in massa bibendum rutrum ac eu massa. Pellentesque in arcu dui. Nulla sollicitudin dui sed commodo congue. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus ante neque, scelerisque et adipiscing sit amet, hendrerit tempus magna. Ut vel eros in sapien condimentum sodales at gravida velit. Nullam dolor enim, lobortis nec hendrerit eget, vulputate sit amet eros. Quisque varius.</p> 
        </div>

        <img src="images/laptop-1.png" class="laptop">

        <div class="q">

            <ul class="bxslider2 question-slide">

                <li>

                    <p>1. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla?</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>

                    <p>2. Nullam odio nibh, faucibus sed felis nec, interdum ornare nulla??</p>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>A.</span> 1/4</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>B.</span> 1/2</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span>C.</span> 1/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="correct"><span>D.</span> 2/3</a><span class="extra">X.X%</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <div class="continue">
              <p><span id="slider-next">
                <a class="bx-next" href="">Next Question</a></span>
                </span></p>
            </div>
    </div>


</li>
```

### My Complete JQuery looks like this

```
$('#questions .question').each(function(){
    $('#questions .extra').hide();
    $(this).find('.q ul a').each(function(){

        $(this).click(function(){ 

            $(this).addClass('picked'); if($(this).hasClass('correct')){ $(this).append('<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Correct!</strong>');} 
            $(this).closest('ul').find('a').unbind( "click" );
            $(this).closest('ul').find('a').click(function(){ return false;});

            $(this).closest('ul').find('a.correct').addClass('picked');
            $('#questions .extra').show(); 



            // if ($('#slider-next a.bx-next').is(".disabled")) {

            //  $('#questions .continue').hide();
            // }
            // else { $('#questions .continue').show(); }


            $('#slider-next a.bx-next').each(function(){

                alert ("It is " + isDisabled);
                var $this = $(this), isDisabled = $this.hasClass('disabled');

                $this.closest('.continue').toggle(isDisabled);
            });

            //$('#questions .continue').show();



            $('#slider-next').click(function(e){
              // alert("Slider1 Next");
              e.preventDefault();
              $(this).parent().parent().hide();
              questionslider.goToNextSlide();
              return false;
            });

            $('#slider-next2').click(function(e){
              // alert("Slider2 Next");
              e.preventDefault();
              $(this).parent().parent().hide();
              questionslider2.goToNextSlide();
              return false;
            });







            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

### What worked half-way is this:-

```
if ($('#slider-next a.bx-next').is(".disabled")) {

                    $('#questions .continue').hide();
                }
                else { $('#questions .continue').show(); }
```

Comment: when you calling this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each element, disabling the `.continue` in context if the element has the `.disabled` class:

```
$('#slider-next a.bx-next').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), isDisabled = $this.hasClass('disabled');
    $this.closest('.continue').toggle(isDisabled);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. I basically want to show it (`$('#questions .continue').show()`) too, if there is no disabled in it. Any idea how?

Comment: So it shows when there is no `disabled` in it and hides when there is a `disabled` in it.

Comment: Hi Steve, `toggle()` handles hiding and showing your element.

Comment: Hi, I just added my complete code. Basically I guess you're code is not being picked up the way I am using it. I incite the code within the click and I guess it has to be used within that consent. Could you please see my updated question. Hopefully I am not making it unnecessarily complex. I am really stuck on this and I'll be thankful if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I changed your code as follows:- $('#slider-next a.bx-next, #slider-next2 a.bx-next').each(function(){

     
        var $this = $(this), isDisabled = $this.hasClass('disabled');
        console.log($this.parent().parent().parent());
        if (isDisabled) {
         $this.parent().parent().parent().hide(); 
        }
        else {
         $this.parent().parent().parent().show();
        }
    });

Comment: `id`s should be unique. You should address that issue first. If elements can be grouped, use a class, I.E: `.slider-next`, not `#slider-next`.